# C: Confusion Regarding The Use of Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm in the middle of reading a C programming book.  I'm currently reading and practising using Xcode with pointers.

I am wondering why this line of code is only printing the first character `H` of a literal character array `string` and not the full string `"Hello"`

```
char *myCharPointer = "Hello";

printf("The value of myCharPointer is %c \n \n", *myCharPointer);
```

I was under the impression that a string literal returns the address of the first character within that array, which then, I thought would automatically print the reset of the characters sequentially.  The reason behind this thought process was a preceding example that demonstrated a similar `string` being passed to a `char` pointer within a function, then the address of that `char` pointer being passed into a `strcpy()` function for all the characters to be read.  I also tried changing the format specifier to `%s`, but the program crashed.

I'm also a little confused why this:

```
int myIntArray[10];
int *myIntArrayPointer;

myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray;
```

And not:

```
int myIntArray[10];
int *myIntArrayPointer;

myIntArrayPointer = &myIntArray;
```

I know that `myIntArray` is not defined as yet, but its just an example

Comment: Please [read the manuals for the functions you use](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: If you replace `%c` with `%s` then you also need to remove the `*` because that format requires a pointer and not a direct value.

Comment: you need to read some more on pointers and array

Comment: The declaration is meant as a mnemonic, you say `const char *foo = "bar";` so the type of *foo is `const char` (a single character). The type of `foo` on the otherhand is `const char *` (i.e. the thing that "%s" expects according to printf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering why this line of code is only printing the first character H of a literal character array string and not the full string "Hello"

First, the pointer `char*` is defined as pointing to a character. In the case of your example, that is `H` in `Hello`. With a string, you are defining data in contiguous memory. For instance,

```
char  [H][e][l][l][o][\0]
index [0][1][2][3][4][5]
```

The pointer is used simply as a way of iterating over each character in memory. This means `myCharPointer = H(0)`, `++myCharPointer = e(1)`, etc.

When you print the string, you would do the following:

`printf("The value of myCharPointer is %s \n \n", myCharPointer);`

> I know that myIntArray is not defined as yet, but its just an example

An integer pointer and an integer array are essentially the same thing in the context of assignment. A pointer can iterate through a block of memory and therefore your straight assignment `myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray` is correct.

**As a side note:**

If you have a regular character `char myChar = 'a';` you can get its address in memory with the `&`. For instance, `char* myCharPointer = &myChar;` -> `myCharPointer` now points to `myChar`. To get the value at the address, simply use the dereferencing operator `*myCharPointer` which would be `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering why this line of code is only printing the first character `H` of a literal character array `string` and not the full string `"Hello"`

```
char *myCharPointer = "Hello";
```

`myCharPointer` is pointer to the first character of the string literal `Hello`, i.e, `H`. Buy using `*` operator in `*myCharPointer` you are dereferencing the pointer `myCharPointer` which will give the value stored at the location pointed by `myCharPointer` which is `H`. That's why you are getting `H`.

> I also tried changing the format specifier to %s, but the program crashed.

`*myCharPointer` is of `char` type and you need `%c` specifier to print a `char`. To print the string literal use `%s` specifier

```
 printf("The value of myCharPointer is %s \n \n", myCharPointer);
```

To print the value of the address use `%p` specifier

```
 printf("The value of myCharPointer is %p \n \n", (void *)myCharPointer);
```

The snippet

```
int myIntArray[10];
int *myIntArrayPointer;

myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray;
```

is valid because `myIntArrayPointer` is `pointer to int` type. Array name are decays to pointer (not always) and hence `myIntArray` is also a pointer to int type and that's why `myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray;` is valid.

```
int myIntArray[10];
int *myIntArrayPointer;

myIntArrayPointer = &myIntArray;
```

`&myIntArray` is of type `int (*)[10]` i.e, pointer to array of 10 integers. As I stated above `myIntArrayPointer` is of type `int *` and hence assignment is not valid .

> I also tried changing the format specifier to %s, but the program crashed.

Comment: you would like to edit the spelling of array in the 6th line. Anyways very nice answer !

Answer (score 1):

First of all it prints a single character because you *tell* `printf` to print a single character (with the `"%c"` format specifier). Secondly, the variable `myCharPointer` does indeed point to the beginning of the string literal `"Hello"` (more specifically it points to the where the character `'H'` is in memory), and when you use the dereference operator `*` you get the *value* of the location that the pointer points to, in this case a single character.

Thirdly, string literal are actually *constant* and read-only, so you should either declare `myCharPointer` as a pointer to constant data, or make it an array. So either

```
const char *myCharPointer = "Hello";
```

or

```
char myCharPointer[] = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

when you assign a string to the pointer the pointer will point at the first character
i think this link might be useful [C Strings](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/)

and for your next question arrays are a bit like pointers myIntArray is the address which points to the first element of the array you should not use '&' with it myIntArray[i] is sth like you are pointing to the i'th element of the array

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are using the `%c` qualifier, which tells `printf` to write a `char` which is pointed by `myCharPointer`. 
It's actually equal to write:

```
char *myCharPointer = "Hello";
printf("The value of myCharPointer is %c \n \n", myCharPointer[0]);
```

I'm sorry but I am unable to show you a little scheme about how `myCharPointer` looks like in RAM.

```
myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray;
```

is correct, because `myIntArray` is yes, an array, but don't forget that array are just syntactic sugar in C. An array is basically a pointer to the first element of the array itself.
There's no difference between:

```
*(myIntArray + 2) = 5;
myIntArray[2] = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for everybody's answers, but still a lot to take in as pointers are literally head benders for my at the moment.  Just a comment about your last two lines of code, is there any point (no pun intended!) in having a pointer for any array data type, when an array, especially an int array when first declared and defined is a pointer anyway?

Comment: I haven't understood what you wanted to mean. May you be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

To print a *string*, you use the `%s` conversion specifier and you do not dereference the pointer:

```
printf("The value of myCharPointer is %s \n \n", myCharPointer);
```

This tells `printf` to print the characters starting at the *address* given by `myCharPointer` until it sees the 0 terminator.

> I was under the impression that a string literal returns the address of the first character within that array

More or less correct; except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

The string literal `"Hello"` has type "6-element array of `char`" (5 characters plus the 0 terminator).  In the declaration

```
char *myCharPointer = "Hello";
```

it is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, nor is it being used to initialize an *array* of `char`, so the above rule applies; it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`", and it *evaluates* to the address of the first character.

> I'm also a little confused why this:
>
> ```
> int myIntArray[10];
> int *myIntArrayPointer;
>
> myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray;
> ```

Going back to the rule above; since the expression `myIntArray` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `int`".

> And not:
>
> ```
> int myIntArray[10];
> int *myIntArrayPointer;
>
> myIntArrayPointer = &myIntArray;
> ```

This time, `myIntArray` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the above rule no longer applies; the type of the expression `&myIntArray` is "pointer to *10-element array of* `int`" (`int (*)[10]`), *not* `int *`.  The types are not *compatible*, so you can't assign one to the other.

Note that the *values* of `myIntArray` and `&myIntArray` are the same; the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array.  It's just the types that differ, but types matter.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is printing a single character instead of the entire string since you are specifying %c , which indicates that a single character should be printed.
To print the entire string, go with

```
char *myCharPointer = "Hello";

printf("The value of myCharPointer is %c \n \n", myCharPointer);
```

(just remove your asterisk sign for myCharPointer)

As for the second part,
**myIntArray** is the name of the int array and it also *points* to the first element of that int array. So you should go with

```
myIntArrayPointer = myIntArray;
```

Comment: This code passes a pointer (`myCharPointer`) to be displayed using the `%c` format specifier, which requires a character, not a pointer.

Comment: But this will work. His problem is that he cannot print the entire string.. and he wants to use pointers. This is a way to do that. Of course if he wanted to just print a single character you are right, but that is **not** the problem specified here :-)

Comment: It will not work. Passing a pointer for a `%c` specifier has behavior not defined by the C standard. In many C implementations, it will attempt to print a byte **of the pointer** as a character. This code is wrong.